# Function for drawing group of dots gives me a warning or doesn't draw at all

Tags: php, random, null, warnings, pixel

The following simple code generates dots on a given image (which is dynamically generated too), but for unknown reason I don't see them ...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
  $xcoords = mt_rand(50, 450);
  $ycoords = mt_rand(50, 450);
  if ($ycoords > 300)
  {
    drawMe($red);
  }
  elseif ($ycoords > 150 && $ycoords < 300)
  {
    drawMe($green);
  }
  else
  {
    drawMe($blue);
  }
```

This is the code for used colors:

```
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 128, 0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);
```

And this is the drawMe() func:

```
function drawMe($color)
{
  ob_start();
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords, $ycoords - 1, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords + 1, $ycoords - 1, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords + 1, $ycoords, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords + 1, $ycoords + 1, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords, $ycoords, $color); // main dot !!!
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords, $ycoords + 1, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords - 1, $ycoords + 1, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords - 1, $ycoords, $color);
  imagesetpixel($im, $xcoords - 1, $ycoords - 1, $color);
  return ob_get_clean();
}
```

If I remove ob_start and ob_get_clean, I've got warning:

```
Warning: imagesetpixel() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/test.php on line 75 to 83
```

That's $im and the background:

```
$im = imagecreate(640, 480);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
```

Comment: Added, this is almost the full source, except php tags, header and imagepng/destroy.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the new $im as new image before you start

you can use imagick class

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(100, 100, new ImagickPixel('red'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');
```

Comment: Why I need to use different API?

Comment: no you don't , i'm just saying if you like to create a new image do like that i posted before i see your definition to $im.

Comment: So, any another ideas where's the problem with missing dots?